# Editor for Amazon Kindle .mobi files

Tags: windows, gratis, mobi

I am looking for a gratis, Windows app which can open  Amazon Kindle *.mobi files and let me perform simple search/replace operations (hopefully with regular expressions).

The app should operate directly on .mobi files; I do not want to have to convert them to another format, edit that & convert back to .mobi I can do that with [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), but cannot be certain that the double conversion won't introduce problems.

Comment: Related: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/2449